# Output of MySql Data in Two Columns from Right to Left

Tags: php, mysql, database

Output of data records from mySql table is required in two columns starting from right side, i.e. records 1 & 2 should appear in the second column while 3 & 4 should display in the first column. Both the columns should be able to display any number of records, not just two that is shown here as an example.

mySql table :

```
1. fname     lname     age     address
2. fname     lname     age     address
3. fname     lname     age     address
4. fname     lname     age     address
```

Code used :

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","mysql_user","mysql_password");
if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);
?>

<style type='text/css'>
#div1, #div2 {float:left; margin-left:50px; width:300px;}
</style>

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member");
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<div id='div1'>";
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   { 
      echo "Sr. No." . " " . $row['srno'] . " " . $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'] . " " . $row['age'] . " " . $row['address'];
   $i++;
   echo "<br/>";
   echo "<br/>";

      if ($i == floor($rowcount / 2)) {

   echo "</div><div id='div2'>";  
    }
   }
echo "</div>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Output from above code :

```
Sr. No. 1. fname   lname   age   address               Sr. No. 3. fname   lname   age   address
Sr. No. 2. fname   lname   age   address               Sr. No. 4. fname   lname   age   address
```

Output required :

```
Sr. No. 3. fname   lname   age   address               Sr. No. 1. fname   lname   age   address
Sr. No. 4. fname   lname   age   address               Sr. No. 2. fname   lname   age   address
```

Comment: have you tried changing your query for it to return the id's in descending order?

Comment: @wrbit  Yes! Did that. But, output displays no. 4 at the top and no. 1 at the bottom.

Comment: This will require putting the results in an array, and manipulating it to display the entries in the order you want

Comment: We note that there is `ORDER BY` clause in the query, so there is no guarantee of the rows will be returned by the query.

Comment: @spencer7593  Thanks, Spencer. Tried that too. But, doesn't help.

Comment: @CodeCruncher: I didn't mean to imply my observation would help, that's why it's a comment, not an answer. I was just pointing out that you may be observing the query returning rows in a particular orde, but there is no guarantee that a subsequent execution will return the rows in the same order. Absent an ORDER BY, the database is free to return the rows in any order. (It's not likely that the order of the rows will change for your query, but the order you observe is *not* guaranteed.)

Comment: @spencer7593  Thanks once again, Spencer. I didn't misunderstand your comments. Was just informing you that `ORDER BY` clause in the query was tried and didn't help in outputting as required. I guess it's the php code that may do the necessary and not mySql query. Any help or comment will be appreciated.

Comment: do you want the result in reverse order? 1,2,3,4 ->4,3,2,1

Comment: @CodeCruncher: Check my answer for `MySQL` solution.

Comment: @feroz akbar  I want the output as shown in my OP. Thanks, anyhow.

Comment: Is there some other way of getting the output as required? May be by specifying an odd/even condition? Like even numbered records should display first and then odd numbered records display next so that Sr. No. 2 is output first and then Sr. No. 1 is displayed next on right side.

Answer (score 0):

**`MySQL` solution:**

You need `ORDER BY FIELD( ...` in your select statement.

```
SELECT * FROM member ORDER BY FIELD( id, 3,4,1,2 )
```

This statement results your records in the following order.

```
3. fname     lname     age     address
4. fname     lname     age     address
1. fname     lname     age     address
2. fname     lname     age     address
```

***Refer to***:

- [Ordering by specific field values with MySQL](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/)
- [MySQL: Sorting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sorting-rows.html)

Comment: Thanks for helping out. But, this is not what is required. `id`  is different from the Sr. No. shown in my OP. I want the Sr. No. ordered in two columns as shown in my OP.

Comment: Using above query results, did run your php `while` written in the posting? What was the result?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what you mean to say. Please explain.

Comment: In your while loop, you reordered display from row1: 1,2, row2: 3,4 to row1: 3,1, row2: 4,2 and constructed td's. Similarly you can use the above sql query results in the same way. I mean, as is or with minor change in `field(...` condition.